# Python Open last file having same extension

Tags: python-3.x

I have many folders say "folder1", "folder2" etc
Each folder inturn has many files with different extensions

`eg:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
file6.txt
file7.txt
file8.txt
file.xlsx
file2.bin`

I want to open the last file in every folder. 
For instance here I want to open the file8.txt as its the last file having extension "txt"
Can anyone please let me know a generic method to do this.

I am a beginner in python.

Comment: How do you identify `last` file ? Is it the latest created file or some other way?

Comment: "last" is relatively defined. last modified? last in lexicographical order?

Comment: #Mayank Porwal Last file can be defined by either time stamp or the name eg: file8.txt.. Here 8 is the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*.txt') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
f = open(latest_file, 'r')
```

You can run this in a loop for all folders. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Considering last means latest timestamp of file this should do :

```
import os
import glob

def get_latest_file(file_loc,file_nm_str):
    file_lst = glob.glob(file_loc+"*" + file_nm_str + "*") 
    latest_file = max(file_lst, key=os.path.getctime)
    return latest_file
```

You can modify * with required extension.